# How should I design my tables in relation database?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, relation

I have a source code that comes in this type of XML which I have to parse and save to database.

```
<stock date="23.2.2016">
    <sth mark="aaa">111</sth>
    <sth mark="bbb">222</sth>
    <sth mark="ccc">333</sth>
</stock>
<stock date="24.2.2016">
    <sth mark="aaa">444</sth>
    <sth mark="bbb">555</sth>
    <sth mark="ccc">666</sth>
</stock>
```

I tried to make two tables with one for stock and one for sth in XML and to relate to them. 
When I tried to populate them I didn't know how to. The problem is I think that my design is bad. If I try to do it with only two tables the second one would become much too big and creating a new table for each stock entry just seems wrong. Any advice or sample code on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was there any specific reason for why you created two tables in the first place? If not, just create one table containing all data plus date (timestamp):

```
aaa | bbb | ccc | date
111 | 222 | 333 | 23.2.2016
...
```

This should suffice and still conforms to normalization principles, since all data is unique to the entry and there's no unnecessary duplication.

Comment: well i tought that it would look like a mess because theres more than 30 of those aaa,bbb ... And data manipulation would also contain lots of code that is not easy to overview.

Comment: According to the given xml-example only the stock date and values for aaa, bbb and ccc seem to change. So those (date, aaa, bbb, ccc) become attributes / columns of your table. Consequently there's no repition of aaa, bbb, ccc because they are columns / column names.

Alternatively you could make a table like this:

``

If that is not the case, you should change your example accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively you could make a table like this:  

`sth mark | sth value | stock date`  `aaa         | 111          | 23.2.2016`  
`bbb         | 222          | 23.2.2016`  
`...`  

the given example implies the simpler and probably less repetitive table structure given in my answer. If that is not the case, change the example accordingly.

Comment: yeah thank you theres just no other way. Due to my lack of experiance i tought that there was way too many columns

Comment: hmm i just found out that there are some stocks in the middle that have different marks and their number. @bitrecycling do you have maybe any suggestion on what to do

Comment: You could go with the approach from my second comment, it's fully flexible, but also requires repitition of the mark value. This is probably not as minimal as you wanted it, but the only possibility, if you don't know (yet) if there's some other possible values for "sth mark". 

table columns: `sth mark | sth value | stock date`